# Android Push notification GCM php and MySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Hi im new to php and my sql. Im Developing android push notification application, following by [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/).

i have already created gcm database and table.  when i inserting to the data from test.php, I got the following error form the register.php,..
but the entered data is stored in the data base correctly.

in the config.php i set the API KEY from the google project
this is the post request url
https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send

this is the error 
{"multicast_id":6982561382500500424,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}

appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The registrationId you use in your test.php should be a valid registrationId that the client app received.

Here is more details on all possible error responses and what they mean:
[Interpreting Error Codes](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html#error_codes)

Comment: thanks for the reply. Test from a device with real data..

Answer (score 0):

You may get wrong API KEY from Google. You should choose "Create a new server key"

[image]

Comment: not the answer.. yes the same way i created the server key.. did again and got the same result..